# How to loop through files with executable permissions?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to loop through several folders with different files. However, some files can be recognized and some cannot. I looked more into it and realized that it's only the green files that I cannot get the correct path. After reading more about it, it looks like green files are executable with this type of permission "-rwxrwxr--". I can loop through red files with this permission "-rw-rw-r--".

Here's a quick example of the loop.

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
echo    /storage/data/${i}_*_R1.fastq.gz
done
```

For files with with this permission "-rw-rw-r--", the loop returns paths like this `/storage/data/Sample1_ABCD_R1.fastq.gz.` However, for files with permission "-rwxrwxr--" the output is this `/storage/data/Sample2_*_R1.fastq.gz` and I cannot process them. I tried removing the executable permission using `chmod -x filename` but it says `Operation not permitted`. I think this is because the files were originally created by someone else and shared with me. Is there an easier way to loop through these files without having to do it manually?
Thanks!

Comment: _and I cannot process them_: How do you process them and what error do you get?

Comment: Permissions on individual files will not cause wildcard expansions like this to fail; something else is going on. What do you mean by "red" and "green"? Files don't intrinsically have colors, although some programs (like `ls --colors`) can add colors for display purposes. Do you have color codes in your array entries (in `arr`) or something like that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what's going on but the array is ```declare -a arr=("Sample1" "Sample2")```. I'm talking about the color codes that is assigned by linux when you ```ls``` to distinguish files from others. For example if you run ```chmod +x file.sh```, it turns green. I have to feed a program the path for these files but for some reason the wildcard isn't working for these files. Instead, the program returns an error that the file does not exist.

Comment: I think there has to be something other than execute permissions causing this. If you run `echo /storage/data/Sample2_*_R1.fastq.gz` by hand, does it expand to the actual filename or print with a "*"? Also, you said the files were shared with you; how were they shared, how are they stored on your system (are they on a server, external disk, anything like that)? Are they in the same directory as the ones that work, or somewhere else? Finally, if you add execute permission (`chmod +x`) to a file that works, does it *stop* working?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the -x test flag to see if the file is executable by the current user.

```bash
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
    test -x "$i" && echo "$i is executable"
done
```

Comment: The test doesn't return anything. I'm assuming it's because it isn't executable and they shouldn't be.

Comment: If they are scripts, you could check the first line.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach is by using `find`. You could do this in commandline:

`find -executable -exec do_stuff_with_what_find_found {} \;`

If you just wanted to find files that had execute permission, just use `find -executable` and `find` will return results based on your current working directory.

`-exec` flag executes given shell command upon the files that pass your given test, in this case is whichever file has execute permission.